# How to determine state of radio box triggered by another element in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So the deal is that i update radiobox elements by clicking on div elements.
So for example i have 3 divs and there's 1 radio box inside each div.

When you click on div the radio box gets **checked**, but problem is that this way .change() event does not work.

How would i get result where i know when particular radiobox has lost :checked status?

Here is code that i currently have:

> ```
> $('#payment_method_cards, #payment_method_ibank_swe, #payment_method_bp').click(function(){
>     $(this).children('input[name="payment_method"]').attr('checked','checked');
>     $('input[name="payment_method"]').change(function(){
>         if($(this).val() == 'bp'){
>             alert("Thats the one");
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

The radiobox change only triggered if i click inside radiobox but not when on div.

Comment: You have to understand the difference between a) binding an event handler to an event, and b) executing an event. In the above code, you are doing a), you are binding the change event handler to the change event. What you want to do is trigger the change event, not bind it. Binding the change event should occur on page-load, not inside a click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use labels instead of the DIVs:

```
<label> <input type="radio" value="1"> Male </label>
```

In the above example, clicking on the word "Male" will trigger the change event.

---

I recommend using labels, but if you insist on using DIVs, this code will work for you. The change event is triggered only if the radio box was not checked beforehand.

```
$('#payment_method_cards, ...').click(function(){
    var radio = $(this).children('input[name="payment_method"]');

    if ( !radio[0].checked ) {
        radio.attr('checked', true).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks for valuable explanations on different parts of my code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have an event handler tied to the `div` that triggers `click` or adds the `checked` attribute.  Why not trigger the `change()` function manually after changing the state of the radio button?

```
$("#check-me").bind("click", function() {
    $("#radio-btn1").click().change(); 
    // change radio button state, then trigger 'change' event.
});
```

**Update:** With the code you provided, you would do something like this (**updated** again due to comment from OP):

```
$('#payment_method_cards, #payment_method_ibank_swe, #payment_method_bp').click(function(){
    var $radio = $(this).children('input[name="payment_method"]'); 
    if (!$radio.is(":checked")) {
        $radio.attr('checked','checked').change();
    }
});
```

You should define the `change` handler outside the `click` handler:

```
$('input[name="payment_method"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'bp'){
        alert("Thats the one");
    }
}
```

Comment: Simpler: `.attr('checked', true)`

Comment: Cool, thanks didn't knew that you can use .change() as manual changer :) Only problem now is that each time you click that div you get that alert. Perfectly i would want it to alert only on first time that radio box is checked. Then if it loses checked status and again gained you get alert again.

Comment: @arma I've answered your question

Comment: Bah i'm sorry that i can't accept both answers at once. As if anyone come to this page for future reference i marked the cleaner answer. Sorry Andrew.